# Sending/printing a key with jQuery.Trigger

Tags: jquery, triggers

i think i have read every page google knows about which has these keywords, and nothing works for me.

what i have is a form input, and a button next to it [not submit], and what i want is for the button click to trigger an 'enter' key click. [this will respectively run another function which is already working..]

i've tried

```
<input id='inputBtn' type='button' .... onclick='$('#otherInput').trigger('keypress',[13]);' >
```

and also putting it in a function and then running it from onclick, or making a

```
$('#inputBtn').click(function().....
```

nothing works for me please help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').trigger({
  type:  'keypress',
  which:  13
});
```

--EDIT--

you might want to extend that with

```
keyCode: 13,
charCode: 13
```

etc.

Comment: do you have any link with the key numbers for me?

Comment: there are lots off
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

Comment: merci @jAndy ! what is the difference between keyCode and charCode ?

Comment: for real?

snippet from your profile
---UI-Designer/Programmer. (Mostly HTML, JS and CSS)---

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide some example code.  I can't think of any reason you couldn't just have the second function (that runs when enter is pressed) being called by the click event on your button.

```
function onEnter()
{
 //Do something
}

jQuery("#inputButton").live("click",onEnter());
```

Should work.

Comment: i cant tell you how i laughed when i read this, since this was exactly the kind of thing i was looking for, i just there has to be another way.

not a programmer, thanks pants@dan.


[works perfectly, and much more elegantly]